# How to get child-index of element in prototype

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs, traversal

If I have a structure like this:

```
<ul>
   <li class="golden-delicious">Golden Delicious</li>
   <li class="mutsu">Mutsu</li>
   <li class="mcintosh">McIntosh</li>
   <li class="ida-red">Ida Red</li>
</ul>
```

and a selector

```
$$('li.mutsu')[0]
```

that returns an element, how can I get the index of this element within its parent child collection? I need the index value "1" of li.mutsu.

Comment: .getElementsByTagName("li").[1] is not enough?

Comment: No, because this is part of a function that's returning different elements and needs to find out the child index dynamically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `.previousSiblings().size()`

Comment: +1 - clever. Surprising that there is no prototype equivalent to jQuery's `.index` (at least, not one that I could find).

Comment: Indeed, really clever! Thank you. I also had jQuerys index-function in mind, but havent't find an equivalent so far.

Comment: Prototype arrays have an `indexOf` function but this answer is neater.

Comment: I think indexOf() does not help here as you have to check DOM elements against each other.